# Unsatisfed LinkError in java?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jython

I am running jython to connect to Bladelogic managers for which i need to connect to it. When i try to do it. It says following Error:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no XJNIService in java.library.path.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Regards
Gnash-85

Answer (score 1):

Some class you are using requires native libraries and the JVM cant find them. You need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH on linux/unix or start with the property -Djava.library.path=PATH to where the libraries are located (the later works on both linux and windows).

For example: "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/libs java -cp foo jython.repl"

There should be a flag you can pass to the jvm to output diagnostic info regarding jni loads.